# pandas read_csv with chunksize argument produces an iterable which can only be used once?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm opening a file named `file.dat` using `pandas.read_csv`. `file.dat` contains several hundred million lines, so its size exceeds my available ram. The file looks like:

```
2.069921794968841368e+03 4.998600000000000000e+04
2.069943528235504346e+03 4.998600000000000000e+04
2.070004614137329099e+03 4.998300000000000000e+04
2.070022949424665057e+03 4.998100000000000000e+04
2.070029861936420730e+03 4.998000000000000000e+04
....
.... 
....
```

The code snippet to open the file is:

```
file = pd.read_csv("file.dat", 
                     delim_whitespace = True, index_col = None,
                     iterator = True, chunksize = 1000)
```

I have a function `process` which iterates through `file` and performs an analysis:

```
def process(file, arg):
    output = []
    for chunk in file: # iterate through each chunk of the file 
        val = evaluate(chunk, arg) # do something involving chunk and arg
        output.append(val) # and incorporate this into output
    return output # then return the result
```

This all works fine. However, to do multiple runs of `process(file, arg)`, I have to rerun the `file = pd.read_csv` snippet. For example, this does not work:

```
outputs = []
for arg in [arg1, arg2, arg3]:
    outputs.append(process(file, arg))
```

but this does:

```
outputs = []
for arg in [arg1, arg2, arg3]:
    `file = pd.read_csv("file.dat", 
                         delim_whitespace = True, index_col = None,
                         iterator = True, chunksize = 1000)
    outputs.append(process(file, arg))
```

The essential problem is that the iterable produced by `pd.read_csv` is only usable once. Why is this so? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, it produces *an iterator*, which is only good for one use. That is how *iterators* are supposed to behave. Otherwise, this would be pointless, it wouldn't save space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior because the `TextFileReader` object, which the `pd.read_csv` function with the specified `chunksize` parameter returns, is an **Iterator, not an Iterable**.

I admit that there is some confusing wording around what object you will get returned. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking) in the documentation you're being told that you get an "iterable object". But if you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/io/parsers.py#L536-L702) in the pandas.io.parsers.py file you will find that the `TextFileReader` object is an iterator as the class contains a `__next__` method.

So, in your case `file` is an iterator which is used up after one call of the `process` function. You can observe a similar effect in this toy example with a numpy.array:

```
import numpy as np


arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = iter(arr1)


def process(file, arg):
    output = []
    for chunk in file:  # iterate through each chunk of the file
        val = chunk ** arg  # do something involving f and arg
        output.append(val)  # and incorporate this into output
    return output  # then return the result


outputs1 = []
for arg in [1, 2, 3]:
    outputs1.append(process(arr1, arg))

outputs2 = []
for arg in [1, 2, 3]:
    outputs2.append(process(arr2, arg))
```

Then you get:

```
>>> outputs1
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9], [1, 8, 27]]
>>> outputs2
[[1, 2, 3], [], []]
```

Comment: excellent. Thanks @apitsch. I appreciate your digging into the pandas source. I probably should have done this myself

Comment: @kevinkayaks You're welcome. I hope you find a way to process your data efficiently.